# Getting rid of "Don't save"/"Cancel"/"Save" animation in OS X

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/th4Hc.png]

This has always been an annoyance for me. In previous versions of OS X, when closing a document via ⌘w a simple drop down would appear, with the options to not save, cancel or save, and it would appear instantly.
Recently (not sure whether since 10.7 or 10.8), you are immediately prompted with a drop down allowing you to save directly. Which is great, except that this drop down doesn't appear immediately, as it needs to perform an animation before being operable.
While this isn't much of a problem singularly, it can become somewhat of a nuisance when having to deal with multiple files.

So, **is there any way to get rid of the sliding animation?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a key for NSWindowResizeTime to .GlobalPreferences.plist:

```
defaults write -g NSWindowResizeTime -float 0.001
```

`-float 0` doesn't work, but `-float 0.001` effectively disables the animations.

The setting also affects the animations for:

- Changing tabs in preference windows
- Zooming windows
- Opening and closing the version browser
- Entering and exiting custom full screen windows in WriteRoom

You can delete the setting with `defaults delete -g NSWindowResizeTime`.